# foreach items from database if month is same

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have two identical html tables with foreach loop. One database table and I want to get values for these tables, but I want to seperate these so

In table 1 there is values that which have been added January. Is that possible like this?

date field format is:

// 2018-12-09 06:54:49

Example:

```
// if month = January 
// generate items that date month is January

<table id="one">
  foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : // My foreach loop
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $item->name; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $item->date; ?></td>
    </tr>
   endforeach;
</table>

// if month = February 
// generate items that date month is February  

<table id="two">
  foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : // My foreach loop
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $item->name; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $item->date; ?></td>
    </tr>
   endforeach;
 </table>
```

Comment: Did my post helped you?